# Ada. Building "main" file takes forever when tasking

Tags: task, ada

I have this simple tasking (threads) program that I'd like to run but building it takes forever (30 seconds or more). It makes it exhausting to have to wait for the build to be built before running the program every-time, especially when I all want to do is change something insignificant, like adding a Put sentence here or there.

This is the program I have been running for reference. I am using GPS 2016. I am a beginner in Ada.

```
    with Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO; 
use Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Main is
task First_Task;
   task body First_Task is
   begin
      for Index in 1..4 loop
         delay 2.0;
         Put("This is in First_Task, pass number ");
         Put(Index, 3);
         New_Line;
      end loop;
   end First_Task;

   task Second_Task;
   task body Second_Task is
   begin
      for Index in 1..7 loop
         delay 1.0;
         Put("This is in Second_Task, pass number");
         Put(Index, 3);
         New_Line;
      end loop;
   end Second_Task;

   task Third_Task;
   task body Third_Task is
   begin
      for Index in 1..5 loop
         delay 0.1;
         Put("This is in Third_Task, pass number ");
         Put(Index, 3);
         New_Line;
      end loop;
   end Third_Task;

begin
 for Index in 1..5 loop
 delay 0.7;
      Put_Line("This is in the main program.");
end loop;
end Main;
```

Comment: Nice MCVE! FSF Gnat 4.9.3 (Debian Jessie) builds it in a fraction of a second (basic text editor, `gnatmake main.adb` in a console.)  Sounds like a GPS install problem, I think we need to know your OS and how you installed GPS to see if anyone can reproduce. Or head over to `getadanow.com` to see if there's a suitable alternative.

Comment: I am using GPS 2016 on a Windows 10 machine. I just encountered the problem right now when i started with tasking. It has built everything up until now (tasks) extremely quick. When I installed my GPS I went through libre.adacore.com. I selected the windows x86 Windows (32-bit) and ran the installer. It's a while since I did it, but I am pretty sure that is how I did it.

Comment: The Windows version of the GNAT compiler is still 32 bit. No problem. Modern x86 CPUs operate in both 32 and 64 bit modes.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I selected the 32 bit version because it was the only one available (but it seems like that's an okey thing to do). My CPU barely spikes and hovers around 10%-20% when building the program. Ada only takes up 3% CPU when building. I don't really feel confident enough in my skill to install another kind of compiler and set a path (and all that), unfortunately.

Comment: Hmmm. Any funny or unusual Python installations? GPS relies on Python a lot and I've heard of some oddities as a result of version confusion ... but nothing like this. As an experiment, it ought to be possible to run the build command (gprbuild whatever.gpr) from a command line. Also : a few years ago I heard rumours of anti-virus foulups too. Possible?

Comment: @BrianDrummond I disabled my anti-virus (Avast Anti-virus), and that seems to have solved the problem. Now it builds quickly again. I guess my Anti-virus was halting the process and scanning the file without notifying me. Avast usually does notify you when it is searching through something though, so it's weird it didn't in this case. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't get why people would use avast anyway... afaik it is one of the worst av anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Posting an answer to help searchability for future users. If you find the full solution, exactly why your AV software does this and a clean solution, don't hesitate to post and accept your own answer.

First, the MCVE enabled a quick test, revealing nothing wrong with either the code or at least one Gnat compiler (Linux x86-64, Debian Jessie, gcc4.9.3) pointing at an installation-specific problem.

The installation in question is Gnat GPL-2016 (32 bit) on Windows-10, with GPS as the IDE, and AVAST anti-virus software.

Previous problem reports and rumour pointed at two possible candidates,

- unusual Python installations - GPS depends on Python, and finding an unexpected Python version is rumoured to cause some troubles
- Anti-virus software interacting with the IDE in unexpected ways.

Of these, the latter is confirmed to be the problem, and disabling AV during program build restores acceptable build times. (This isn't specific to Ada or Gnat, I've seen it on FPGA development tools too)

So we have a temporary workaround.

The next step might be to identify why AVAST is allergic to the build process, and disable its reaction to false positives, to maintain AV protection during programming sessions.

Possible candidates may be the intermediate .o and .ali files (Object and Ada Linker), or intermediate "binding" files `b~whatever.ads/b` which stitch the Ada code to runtime system and OS.

Most likely, the `b~whatever.o` object files spark an allergic reaction when they link to unusual OS primitives for process manipulation, to implement Ada tasking. Possibly this resembles virus behaviour closely enough to attract attention.

One answer may be to teach Avast not to scan your Ada project's build folder, or to filter what it scans by file type. But I can be no further help, and I encourage a better answer from anyone who finds one.